# Procedure returning zero rows when passing where clause as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My procedure returning nothing when pass where clause condition as parameter. Below is the example query and I am passing `@strWhereClauseField` & `@strWhereClauseValue` as a parameter. It works fine when I convert my query in string and execute it. But I don't want to use query string because order by is not working in query string.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
     Id int identity(1,1), Product varchar(10)
)

INSERT @Data VALUES ('HP2030'), ('HP2031'), ('HP2032'), ('HP2033');

DECLARE @strWhereClauseField NVARCHAR(1000) = '1'
DECLARE @strWhereClauseValue NVARCHAR(1000) = '1'

SET @strWhereClauseField = '@Data.Product'
SET @strWhereClauseValue = '''HP2030'''

SELECT * 
FROM @Data 
WHERE @strWhereClauseField = @strWhereClauseValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE    @strWhereClauseField NVARCHAR(1000) = '1'
DECLARE     @strWhereClauseValue NVARCHAR(1000) = '1'
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @strWhereClauseField='Product'
SET @strWhereClauseValue='''HP2030'''

SET @QUERY = 'DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
 Id int identity(1,1)
,Product varchar(10)
 )
INSERT @Data VALUES
(''HP2030'');
INSERT @Data VALUES
(''HP2031'');
INSERT @Data VALUES
(''HP2032'');
INSERT @Data VALUES
(''HP2033'');
SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE '+@strWhereClauseField+'='+@strWhereClauseValue+''
EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Comment: appreciate your answer but i cannot use query string because order by is not working in query string and my original query is truncated due to its length.

Comment: @user1891251 `ORDER BY` works perfectly fine if you include it in the string. And exactly how long is your query that it doesn't fit in `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Length is 5000 but it can vary based on parameters

Comment: @user1891251 5000 fits comfortably within `varchar(max)` Did you actually try this answer?

Comment: I tried and finally get it with varchar(max) using string query and order by working is fine now. thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are doing will not work in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) as SSMS sees the query as so:

```
SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE '@Data.Product' = '''HP2030'''
```

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
     Id int identity(1,1), Product varchar(10)
)

INSERT @Data VALUES ('HP2030'), ('HP2031'), ('HP2032'), ('HP2033');

DECLARE @strWhereClauseField NVARCHAR(1000) = '@Data.Product'
DECLARE @strWhereClauseValue NVARCHAR(1000) = '''HP2030'''
DECLARE @strOrderByColumn NVARCHAR(1000) = 'Product'


DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM @Data WHERE ' + @strWhereClauseField + '=' + @strWhereClauseValue + ' ORDER BY ' + @strOrderByColumn

EXEC sp_executesql(@sql)
```

Comment: Just `EXEC(@sql)`  You also have a problem that the scope in which `EXEC(@sql)` runs doesn't have access to the table variable. You'll need to use a more 'accessible' table or wrap table declaration and loading into `@sql`  Finally `@WhereClauseField == '@Data.Product'` doesn't work. Either drop the table prefix or use an alias.